# Aquo metal complex structure

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds

> **Draw** the structure of the complex $\ce{Co(NO_3)_2*6H_2O}$ **i)** without and **ii)** with one of the nitrates being in the coordination sphere as a bidentate ligand and **identify** if the inversion center is present in the complexes. Inversion is a symmetry operation that translates every atom through the center to the opposite side.

The first part seemed pretty straightforward and I drew the following structure:

[image: Aquo complex structure]

From the structure above, I concluded that there is indeed an inversion center at the cobalt ion.

I'm not so sure about the second structure though. Since the cobalt complex already has six ligands, how could there be a nitrate as a bidentate ligand as well?

Comment: Who said nitrate cannot be exchanged with water in the inner sphere?

Comment: You drew the arrows in the first structure backwards. Those should point from the water to the cobalt.

Comment: @Zhe There should not be *any arrows*. Using dative bonds for depicting coordination complexes is not acceptable. See https://doi.org/10.1351/pac200880020277, p. 292.

Comment: To condense the previous two comments: Yes, there shouldn’t be any arrows at all but *if* you’re going to defy the recommendation (and there can be a good reason for it; e.g. I refuse to use the chemically inaccurate recommendations for phosphorus/sulphur and related compounds), you should do it properly which involves the arrows pointing from the electron donor to the electron acceptor ($\ce{H2O\bond{->}Co}$).